# Ошибка "A packet has been tampered with in transit" при подключении к серверу

Tags: unity3d, клиент-сервер

Изучаю мультиплеер. Создал простой проект с двумя кнопками. При нажатии на первую сервер запускается, а при нажатии на вторую должно происходить подключение. Тестирую на одном ноутбуке. Сам скрипт:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string server_IP = "localhost";
    private int server_Port = 7777;
    private int players_Limit = 5;

    public void CreateServer ()
    {
        Network.InitializeSecurity ();
        Network.InitializeServer (players_Limit, server_Port, false);
    }

    public void FindServer ()
    {
        Network.Connect (server_IP, server_Port);
    }

    private void OnServerInitialized ()
    {
        Debug.Log ("Server Initialized");
    }

    private void OnPlayerConnected (NetworkPlayer player)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Player Connected " + player.ipAddress);
    }
}
```

Создание происходит успешно, но при попытке подключения консоль редактора выдает ошибку:

> A packet has been tampered with in transit.

Почему?

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в защите.

```
Network.InitializeSecurity ();
```

Не стал вникать в суть так как в новой версии движка данный метод отсутствует, обновился, и понял почему.

> The legasy networking system has been removed in Unity 2018.2. Use Unity Multiplayer and NetworkIdentity instead.

Но это уже совсем другая история..